# mysql character encoding

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a MySQL server with the following settings:

```
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  utf8
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    latin1
character_set_system    utf8
```

I have a Java client that connects to this db using DBCP with this config:

```
 <bean id="dsJoomla" class="hu.eutrust.wsfresh.CustomDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${joomla.db.driver}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${joomla.db.user}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${joomla.db.pass}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${joomla.db.url}"/>
        <property name="connectionProperties" value="characterEncoding=UTF-8;useUnicode=true;"/>
    </bean>
```

Then I perform somewhere in the code an update like this:

```
template.update("insert into test (nev) values (:nev)", new MapSqlParameterSource("nev", "Árvíztűrő"));
```

After I check the results in phpMyAdmin I see a row:

```
ID  NEV
2 Árvízt?r?
```

The ő and ű characters that are not in the latin1 set are bad. I suppose this is because the character_set_server is latin1. But using phpMyAdmin I can manually edit the record and enter 'Árvíztűrő' and after that the record is correct. So I suppose it is possible to enter the desired value into the database with these settings. How can I do it with my Java client? How shall I configure the connection? Why do my ő and ű chars go wrong if the connection if 100% utf8?

show create table test output is:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `NEV` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

show create database joomla output is:

```
CREATE DATABASE `joomla` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */
```

Comment: please provide the output of `show create table test;`  and `show create database <your database name here>;`.

Comment: according to http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html the `connectionProperties` must be separated with ;

Comment: updated the question with the required `show`'s

Comment: Ah right, it's delegated through DBCP. Nevermind the comment then.

Comment: if I could not have inserted the ő and ű characters with phpMyAdmin then I would not have posted this question. but if phpMyAdmin can insert ő and ű into this latin1 database, then I want it too from Java.. :-)

Comment: still very intrested, anyone else..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection properties set through the DBCP connection pool bean were not treated as appending them to the JDBC url.

So finally appending `?characterEncoding=UTF-8&useUnicode=true` to the connection url helped me out.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Eclipe, did you check your encoding:

- Window -> Preference -> General -> workspace
- right click at project -> property -> resource

changing it to UTF-8 may help.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the problem has nothing to do with the encoding of my Java code..

Comment: Did you check that? You may see 'Árvíztűrő' correctly in your eclipse (because you are just using an encoding supporting those chars) but it may not consistant with your url connection string which is "characterEncoding=UTF-8;useUnicode=true;"

Comment: Before the SQL update I echoed the string in the console, to double check things. Second: the program is also using a different database and there is no problem with characters on that connection.